# GitHub Actions to push to Azure Artifacts: Unable to load the service index for source ' ' Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (unaut)

Tags: github, azure-devops, nuget, github-actions, azure-artifacts

I wanted to create a Github workflow that push feed to Azure Artifacts. I carefully followed the article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/github-actions?view=azure-devops) and the tutorial [here](https://github.com/Azure/actions-workflow-samples/blob/master/PackageManagement/nuget.yml). However, I keep getting this error

`error: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org>/<proj>/_packaging/<proj>/nuget/v3/index.json. error:   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).`

I created a PAT for all accessible organizations, granted it full access and added it in my Github Action secrets just as the docs says but the error persists. Does anyone have idea what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the workflow is actually using another action `actions/setup-dotnet@v1`to build and publish the package. Turned out this action does not properly pass the personal access token as api key in the nuget push command. I created an issue [here](https://github.com/actions/setup-dotnet/issues/370) which was not resolved as at now. However, I was able to resolve the issue by directly adding `--api-key ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}` to dotnet nuget push command. My resulting command looks like:

```
- name: 'dotnet publish'
  run: dotnet nuget push bin/Release/*.nupkg --api-key ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

This works for both Azure Artifacts and Github Registry.

Answer (score -1):

Have your check the corresponding project and org build service account with `<ProjName> Build Service (<OrgName>)` and `Project Collection Build Service (<OrgName>)` have the enough role access permission in your target feed?

[image]

Comment: I just checked this, both are Contributors, is there any setting where I can change?

Comment: So I was able to change their role to owner but it's still throwing 401 at Github Action.

Comment: The question is asking about GitHub Actions, not Azure Pipelines. PCBS/PBS aren't involved here.